# how to migrate live wordpress site to my localhost with or without plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, migration, localhost

I couldn't trace the issue while migrating.

I am using XAMPP server in local machine and I have tried to export live site and then import it by "all in one wp migration" plugin but I got "theme not found" error when I visit my site locally. the website is working perfectly on the server.

I have performed the following steps:

1. export and download site from the server's wp-admin panel.
2. install and activate "all in one wp migration" in my localhost wp-admin.
3. import the downloaded site in my localhost.
4. now it prompts "successfully imported" and have the link for setup permalinks.
5. when I click on it I found internal server error.

Comment: Try enabling [WP_DEBUG](https://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG) and get some more information on what might go wrong.

Comment: Did you copy the theme into your `wp-content/themes` dir locally?

Comment: how is this a php question ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to perform a manual migration which is done in few easy steps:

1) Archive the folder of your website from your hosting account;
2) Go to the phpMyAdmin and export the database connected with the Wordpress (which you can see by inspecting the wp-config.php file, where you can find the database username / database name and password);

The next step is to download both of the 'backups' of your website (the archive and database export) then simply extract the archive in your xampp section where it is loading and then create a database on your local phpMyAdmin where you can import the one from your hosting account. By following those steps you should have successfully migrated the database and website files as they need to be without relaying on a plugin that could (and will) mess things up. If you encounter any issues afterwards as mentioned in the previous replies enable the debugging from the wp-config.php file and enable the 'Display Errors' from your PHP.ini of your XAMPP.

- Also make sure that the php version that you are running on XAMPP is the same as the one of your host, to make sure that there aren't any issues such as plugins requiring higher version or lower one.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

use All-in-One WP Migration Wordpress

Comment: please elaborate your answer, as the OP say he got "theme not found", why is your solution going to work?

Comment: change permalink in your wordpress settings after backup import